# Scale tikzpicture logo produced by newcommand

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

I have created a command to use a logo in my document. But when I have to place in the `titlepage`, I don't know how to scale it. Meanwhile, I could use it in headers.

```
\newcommand{\Logo}{

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \definecolor{bij}{RGB}{44,51,129}
    \path [fill=bij] (0mm,0mm)--(2.9992mm,0mm)--(2.9992mm,9.1089mm) -- (0mm,9.1089mm)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could try:

```
\scalebox{0.6}{
    \Logo
}
```

I am not too familiar with creating commands but this is a possible  quick fix.